# How can i add additional function parameters to assign attributes to an img?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is a jquery plugin that i've found, that creates an img element and appends it to a parent element.

```
$.fn.loadImg = function(src, f){ return this.each(function(){ var i = new Image(); i.src = src; i.onload = f; this.appendChild(i);}); }
```

How can i add paramaters attrName, attrVal to the function that would assign whatever attributes to the image before appending it?

Comment: Do you want just one attribute or any number of attributes?

Comment: Just one attr at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$.fn.loadImg = function(src, f, attrName, attrVal) {
  return this.each(
    function() {
      var i = new Image();
      i.src = src;
      i.onload = f;

      i[attrName] = attrVal;
      // alternatively:
      // i.setAttribute(attrName, attrVal);

      this.appendChild(i);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: @Babiker: How are you calling it? You should be able to use it like this, for example: `$(something).loadImg(src, f, 'alt', 'some text')`

Comment: I see... my attributes order was different, i had the callbalck as last attr, but didn't change my calling order after pasting your code.  Thanks.

Comment: @casablanca, what i did fixed one error, but even after that its not adding the attributes.

Comment: @Babiker: I'm not sure what attribute you're trying to set, but I've added an alternative to my answer; you could try that.